# Asyncio or Threading with while loop, and Tkinter in the blend

Tags: tkinter, while-loop, python-asyncio

UPDATED. A solution has been found!!

This was my issue: I have a class Metronome(), which plays a beat that need to be on a while loop, and I use Tkinter to show the updated tempo on display (plus other information).

The user is be able to change the tempo (and other functions for each metronome) and run multiple independent metronomes.

My issue is that my beat() is not running while Tkinter is displaying the information. I need to close Tkinter's window for the beat() to start :/

Any logic advice

```
import time
import keyboard
import tkinter as tk
import asyncio

class Metronome():
    
    def __init__(self, inst_number, tempo=20, active=True):
        self.inst_number = inst_number
        self.tempo = tempo
        self.active = active
    
    async def beat(self):
        while True:
            if self.active:
                print(f'Metronome {self.inst_number} plays Tick')
                await asyncio.sleep(60/self.tempo)
            self.update()
    
    def up_tempo(self):
        self.tempo +=1
        print(self.tempo)

    def down_tempo(self):
        self.tempo -=1
        print(self.tempo)

    def update(self):
        keyboard.on_press_key("up", lambda _: self.up_tempo())
        keyboard.on_press_key("down", lambda _: self.down_tempo())

def update_tk(arg, frame, var_tempo, metronomes):
    tempos = []
    
    for metronome in metronomes:
        metronome.update()
        tempos.append(metronome.tempo)
    
    for metronome in range(len(metronomes)):
        var_tempo = tk.Label(frame, text=f'Tempo {tempos[metronome]}', bg='white', fg='black', font=('Helvetica', 14))
        var_tempo.grid(row=1, column=metronome)
    
    arg.after(20, lambda: update_tk(arg, frame, var_tempo, metronomes))

def tkinter_ui(metronomes):
    
    tempos = [0] *len(metronomes)

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('Metronome')
    root.eval("tk::PlaceWindow . center")

    frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='white')

    for i in range(len(metronomes)):
        frame.columnconfigure(i, weight=1)

    for i in range(len(metronomes)):
        dummy_name = tk.Label(frame, text=f'Metronome {i}', bg='white', fg='red', font=('Helvetica', 20))
        dummy_name.grid(row=0, column=i)

        var_tempo = tk.Label(frame, text=f'Tempo {tempos[i]}', bg='white', fg='black', font=('Helvetica', 14))
        var_tempo.grid(row=1, column=i)

    frame.pack(pady=50)
    
    update_tk(root, frame, var_tempo, metronomes)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You don't need threads for this program. Are you interested in non-thread solutions? If so, do some research on tkinter's `after` method.

Comment: Hi @BryanOakley, thanks for your recommendation! I change threading for asyncio and got into Tkinter's `after` method, and I believe is going the right way: The updated display is working great :) but I got stuck with the beat() of the metronome. It runs on a while loop, but I can't make them work together. Any advice on that issue? (I updated the code) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution to this problem was to use Threading + Tkinter, or Asyncio + Threading + Tkinter.

I am sharing a link to the solution Threading + Tkinter, where you can see and try out why it makes sense to this project to use Threading + Tkinter (MIDI controller nanoKontrol2 from Korg)

here: https://github.com/mCrozzoli/Independent-Multi-Metronome-System.git

and here I am sharing the simple metronome version with the Asyncio+Threading+Tkinter solution (add it to the previous block of code)

```
from threading import Thread

def aio_thread(metronomes):
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

    tasks = [loop.create_task(metronomes[i].beat()) for i in range(len(metronomes))]
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*tasks))
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        print("> asyncio: stopped manually")
        pass

metronomes = [Metronome(i) for i in range(2)] 

# start metro thread
metro_thread = Thread(target=lambda: aio_thread(metronomes))
metro_thread.start()
#Start Tkinter
tkinter_ui(metronomes)
```